# Datapickers cmp with today to exe jQuery code

Tags: html, date

I have created this code:

```html
<div class="option">
    <label for="date">Date de debut de reservation</label>
    <input type="date" id="datepickerFrom" ui-date="dateOptionsFrom" ng-model="datepickerFrom" class="form-control ng-empty hasDatepicker ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-ui-date-validator" name="datepickersFrom" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" min="<?php echo $today; ?>"  required>
    <script>
        var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
        document.getElementsByName("datepickersFrom")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
    </script>
</div>
```

I want to compare the date selected with date of today.

If it is the case that today's day is selected I would like to run this code below:

```
   $("#exptype").append('<option value="fast" selected>Ultra-express 1 heure</option>');
```

otherwise if today's date is not selected, I would like to execute this code:

```
   $("#exptype").append('<option value="stand">Livraison standard 24-48h</option>');
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using angular, right? I presume this given that you have the `ng-model` attribute set on your date input. If that is the case, you can use the angular controller to handle this - see example below.

Also, presuming you are using angular, then you could look at using the [angular date picker controls](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) for a richer/more robust UI control...

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('dateController',function($scope) {
  var today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
  $scope.datepickerFrom = today;  
  $scope.todaySelected = true;
  //this replaces that line you had:
  //document.getElementsByName("datepickersFrom")[0].setAttribute('min', today);
  $scope.minDate = today;

  //when the date changes, store a boolean in our controller scope, to be used in the filter function below
  $scope.dateChanged = function() {
    $scope.todaySelected = ($scope.datepickerFrom == today);
  };
  //define our options - please adjust for your needs
  $scope.expTypeOptions = [ 
    { value: "four hours", text: "4 heure" },        
    { value: "fast", text: "Ultra-express 1 heure" },
    { value: "stand", text: "Livraison standard 24-48h" },
  ];
  //this function handles showing the expType options in the select list,
  //based on the selected date
  $scope.filterOptionsByDate = function(expType) {
     if ($scope.todaySelected) { //hide the 'stand' option
        return expType.value != "stand";
     }
     else { //otherwise show everything except the 'fast' option
        return expType.value != "fast";
     }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="option" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dateController">
  <label for="date">Date de debut de reservation</label>
  <input type="date" id="datepickerFrom" ui-date="dateOptionsFrom" ng-model="datepickerFrom" class="form-control ng-empty hasDatepicker ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-invalid ng-invalid-ui-date-validator" min="{{ minDate }}" ng-change="dateChanged()" name="datepickersFrom" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required >
  <div>
      <select ng-model="expType" ng-options="expType.text for expType in expTypeOptions | filter:filterOptionsByDate">              
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: i use jQuerry 2.2.4 , When i add the 3.1.0 of angular js , i have a lot of erros , does it works with the angularjs 1.5.7 ?????

Comment: angular.js:36 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.23%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A415)
    at angular.js:36
    at angular.js:3906
    at r (angular.js:325)
    at e (angular.js:3872)
    at gc (angular.js:3812)
    at c (angular.js:1444)
    at fc (angular.js:1459)
    at Xc (angular.js:1368)
    at angular.js:21949
    at HTMLDocument.a (angular.js:2573)

Comment: Do you mean _bootstrap CSS_ version 3.1.0? I see [this demo page](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.12.0/) which uses version 1.2.x of Angular with Bootstrap CSS 3.1.0 - please take a look at the examples on that page. If you meant Angular 2 we can look at switching to it - see [angular.io](https://angular.io/) for more info...